# searching for tool to create setup for my software?

Tags: windows, installation

I am searching for tool or software to build wizard installer to be easy to custom and have good UI view.

something like Microsoft Office / Microsoft VS or any good setup process?

Does Microsoft give tools like this?

I am not so familiar with software builds and installation.

Ideas from experts in installation field will be great

Thanks ALL.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Caphyon's Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) and [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

They create Native Setup Applications, with very low overhead, and are very easy to learn with hundreds of examples

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of Visual Studio come with an [installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked.aspx), I'd also recommend the open-source NullSoft NSIS installer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has it's own packaging tool, check it under the sub-menu of tools

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with the [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) toolkit.

There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's very flexible.  The [Wix Tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) is a great resource to help you get started.